# How to specify different actions on each hyperlink

Tags: java, servlets

I have a html page containing different hyperlink.I want to do different actions based upon the hyperlink clicked.How do i differentiate these links in `doGet()` method?

Comment: Check out the `FrontController` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is by adding an `action` query parameter, which would be different on each hyperlink, and treated differently in your `doGet()` method.

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/sys/ExampleServlet?action=doThis">...</a>
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/sys/ExampleServlet?action=doThat">...</a>
```

doGet() logic:

```
if (request.getParameter("action").equals("doThis")) {
    ...
} else if (request.getParameter("action").equals("doThat")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: As Everton said, you have to add them in the hyperlink using a Query parameter... that is by adding ?action=something in your href

Answer (score 0):

Add Action parameter in your link. For example:

```
 ?action=add | ?action=delete | ...
```

Since GET method is NOT recommended for these kind of actions so you need to process CSRF here. If you don;t process CSRF. It is easy to perform action by accident or you may got CSRF attack.

Check this for CSRF: http://java.dzone.com/articles/preventing-csrf-java-web-apps